# How can we make a exe for swing application using ant script

Tags: java, swing

Please help me to create exe using ant script and eclipse.

We want to add private JVM in this exe.

Answer (score 2):

**Ant task**

You may set a launch4j directory property or change the task definition.

Define the task in your Ant build script.

```
<taskdef name="launch4j"
    classname="net.sf.launch4j.ant.Launch4jTask"
    classpath="${launch4j.dir}/launch4j.jar
        :${launch4j.dir}/lib/xstream.jar" />
```

Execute the task!

```
<launch4j configFile="./l4j/demo.xml" />
```

You can set or override the following configuration properties...

```
jar="absolute path or relative to basedir"
jarPath="relative path"
outfile
fileVersion
txtFileVersion
productVersion
txtProductVersion
bindir="alternate bin directory..."
tmpdir="alternate working directory..."
```